# Linebreak in magento product description when NOT using wysiwyg

Tags: magento

I have a Magento webshop with over 17.000 products. Products and their description are imported from CSV files. The descriptions have linebreaks in them - but these are not translated to the frontend view due to the fact the Wysiwyg editor isn't used.

I have found tons of ways to remove extra linebreaks when the wysiwyg editor is used, but none that would help me to add linebreaks when the text editor is used.

Is it possible to automatically add these linebreaks 
 or paragraphs

to the content in the normal / standard text editor automatically? And if so, how do I best proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that your theme overrides the default behaviour in Magento with regard to applying line breaks via php. In the file;

`app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\description.html`

You'll see it outputs the description like;

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
```

It may be that the easiest thing to do is use the same technique used with the short description in the base package and apply the php function [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to it to get your imported line breaks;

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), nl2br($_description), 'description') ?>
```